# TPL Dataflow: What's the difference between these 2 code snippets?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0, tpl-dataflow

I am studying the [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx). Belwo are 2 pieces of code snippet from the official document [Stephen Toub. Introduction to TPL Dataflow (TPLDataflow.docx)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14782) . But I am not fully getting what's the difference between them.

BTW, these 2 code snippets are samples from the document for demo purpose. They are not complete.

1. Downloading Images Sequentially and **Synchronously**

   ```
   var downloader = new ActionBlock<string>(url =>
   {
       // Download returns byte[]
       byte [] imageData = Download(url); 
       Process(imageData);
   });

   downloader.Post("http://msdn.com/concurrency");
   downloader.Post("http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam");
   ```
2. Downloading Images Sequentially and **Asynchronously**

   ```
   var downloader = new ActionBlock<string>(async url =>
   {
       byte [] imageData = await DownloadAsync(url);
       Process(imageData);
   });

   downloader.Post("http://msdn.com/concurrency ");
   downloader.Post("http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam");
   ```

Comment: of course i know. but i need some detailed explanation here. because as I tried, the output looks no different.

Comment: Here's a relevant answer from the MSDN forum. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tpldataflow/thread/1afcff27-eb13-4b0b-92de-4ce067874e47

Answer (score 6):

In your first example, for each piece of data posted, the `ActionBlock` will queue its delegate to the thread pool. The `Download` will block a thread pool thread, and then execute `Process` on that same thread pool thread.

In your second example, for each piece of data posted, the `ActionBlock` will queue its delegate to the thread pool. The `await` will asynchronusly wait for the download, so the thread pool thread is returned to the thread pool during the download. When the download completes, the remainder of the method is queued to the thread pool, and `Process` will execute on a thread pool thread.

So in the general case, the second example is more efficient.

You may find my [`async`/`await` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. In my first example, while the first posted data could block a threadpool thread, I think the second posted data could still run on another threadpool thread. So 2 threadpool threads involved here. In my second example, the first threadpool thread could return to thread pool. So the second thread pool thread may not be necessary. So maybe only 1 threadpool is involved. I hope I made myself clear. But is this correct?

Comment: I just read your comment to James, so if I set the *MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2*, 2 threadpool threads can be involved.

Comment: @smwikipedia Yes, but the synchronous code will block both threads for the whole time it's downloading. On the other hand, the asynchronous code will use both threads only for a short time (once at the start and once at the end of the download), or it could execute both on the same thread (while keeping the downloads parallel).

Comment: `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` determines how many *items* can be simultaneously processed, not how many *threads* will do the processing.